# For what values of $x$ does $x^2-2x+2>0$ hold?

Tags: inequality

Can someone help me solve this inequality? $$x^2-2x+2>0$$

I can't factor this, but I know that $x^2-2x=x(x-2)>0$ when $x$ and $(x-2)$ are the same sign and not zero, so in other words when $x<0$ or $x>2$. I'm not sure if and how that helps though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$x^2-2x+2=x^2-2x+1+1=(x-1)^2+1.$$

Answer (score 3):

Another quick way:

The discriminant of the quadratic is negative;

Thus, no real roots;

Thus, the expression does not change sign;

For $x=0$, the expression is positive;

Thus....

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2-2x+2=(x-1)^2+1\geq 1$, if $x\in \mathbb{R}$.